# Subclass UITableViewController, where do I set it up within the UIViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UIViewController, with a UITableView which takes up half the screen.

I also have a subclassed UITableViewController, but I can't figure out how I would associate the subclassed UITableViewController with my table?

Comment: this one - initWithNibName:bundle: call it when init UITableViewController, this function defined in UIViewController

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: The only association between a UITableView and any sort of ViewController is through the TableView's delegate and datasource. If you, for instance, are subclassing UITableViewController to include some default definitions of the delegate/datasource methods, you'd simply want to make sure the TableView's outlets point to an instance of that subclass. A ViewController somewhere would likely have an outlet to the TableView, but the TableView wouldn't really know about what's at the other end of that connection.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question exactly why you are trying to create a UITableViewController and a UIViewController in this case. Do you have 2 different tables you are trying to control? Or are you trying to do something special to have 2 different controllers managing different parts of a view/subview hierarchy?

Typically, the table for a UITableViewController is created automatically or within a NIB file. From the UITableViewController documentation:

> If a nib file is specified via the initWithNibName:bundle: method
>   (which is declared by the superclass UIViewController),
>   UITableViewController loads the table view archived in the nib file.
>   Otherwise, it creates an unconfigured UITableView object with the 
>   correct dimensions and autoresize mask. You can access this view
>   through the tableView property.

So you would usually not need to associate your subclassed UITableViewController with its table because that is taken care of for you.